# Python - loguru disable traceback on exceptions

Tags: python, loguru

I'm not able to disable the traceback on exceptions even after setting `LOGURU_BACKTRACE` environment variable as False. I've also tried `logger.configure()` method like this.

```
logger.configure(handlers=[
    {"sink": sys.stderr, "backtrace": False}
])
```

but loguru is still showing tracebacks on exceptions. Could someone guide me to disable the traceback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `backtrace` attribute controls the length of the traceback (if enabled, Loguru displays the entire traceback instead of stopping at the try/except frame like the standard exception does).

However, Loguru respects the [`sys.tracebacklimit`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/sys.html#sys.tracebacklimit) value. You can disable traceback by settings it to `0`:

```py
import sys

sys.tracebacklimit = 0
```

If advanced exception formatting configuration is required, you can define your own way of displaying exceptions by using a custom `format` function as explained in the documentation: [Customizing the formatting of exceptions](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/resources/recipes.html#customizing-the-formatting-of-exceptions).